# Get all element once with same javascript file

Tags: javascript

*Note stripe related just javascript design question*

I have integrated stripe(successfully) and quite fascinated of how it works.

The below script only renders two stripe checkout button with the stripe js having be called twice **note stripe js is iife**

How does the last script only gets element with className("stripe-button") that was not called by the first script.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button">
  </script>
</form>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button">
  </script>
</form>
```

Trying to implement the same checkout flow using my js script

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script src="my.js" class="my-button"></script>
</form>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <script src="my.js" class="my-button"></script>
</form>
```

Use as an iife

```
//  my.js
(function(){
var btns = getElementsByClassName('my-button');
console.log(btns);
})()
```

Obviously will to get

```
[Script]
[Script, Script]
```

But one only wants the last script to get all elements since all elements with class 'my-button' have been "rendered". 
In stripe case get all elements and add button

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Your JS uses `getElementById`, but your HTML doesn't have any IDs in it. You run the script twice, but you expect to only get the output from it once.

Comment: There's no such function as `getElementsById`. IDs are supposed to be unique, it makes no sense to try to get more than one button with an ID.

Comment: When it runs the first time, how many of that element are on the page? One. And how many does it find? One. When it runs the second time, how many are now on the page? Two. You get the idea. The IIFE makes no difference.

Comment: Edited the question @quentin

Comment: Edited the question @barmar

Comment: Where does `class="my-button"` come from? Are you using that as a parameter to the Stripe Checkout API, to make it use that class for the button?

Comment: No. just trying to implement(learn) my checkout flow @barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you load `my.js`, it can only access the elements in the DOM that have been loaded so far. So when you load it the first time, there's only one `<script src="my.js" class="my-button"></script>` elements in the DOM, and that's what it shows in the console. When you load it the second time, there are two such elements, so it logs both of them.

To get just the current script being loaded, you can index the collection.

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("my-button");
var this_button = btns[btns.length-1];
```

Comment: Expected that. Then how is it possible for stripe js to only add button twice and not thrice since script one has one `<script src="my.js" class="my-button"></script>` scripts has two elements making all three buttons to be added

Comment: Just get the last element of the collection.

Comment: Works +1 @barmar